# How to make regular expression unique for multiple values

Tags: regex, jmeter

My response having same values at 2 places like

```
http://images.123456_120*75
http://images.123456_120*75
http://images.784217_120*75
http://images.784217_120*75
```

In this I need to capture 123456 & 784217 only one time.

I was using regex as  `http://images.(.+?)_120*75` which extracting all 4 values .But my concern is I need one value among 2 for each. Can u pls help me
thanks in advance ?

Answer (score 0):

One way, is to have **2 post processor** with the same regex. Now, in the **1st** regular extractor use **Match No:** value as **1** and in **2nd** use **Match No:** value as **4**.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: But if the index number of each value isn't known?

Comment: it is ok but we need to pass each variable once as u shown in the image. but not only 2 values are in my response there are a lot actually I want to make them unique and want to pass at once

Answer (score 0):

Doing it using regular expressions is quite tricky, I would recommend going for [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) instead.

1. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the request which returns above images URLs
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   (prev.getResponseDataAsString() =~ "http://images.(\\d+)_120\\*75").findAll().unique().eachWithIndex {match, idx ->
       vars.put('image_' + idx,match.get(1))
   }
   ```
3. If everything goes well you should see the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) generated:

   ```
   image_0=123456
   image_1=784217
   etc.
   ```

Comment: thnku Dmitri i'll try this and let u know.

Comment: it is giving regex.patternsyntaxexception: illegeal/unsupported escape sequence near index 75

Answer (score 0):

This should work,  it captures unique values only once:

```
(\d+)(?:_)(?![\s\S]*\1)
```

[Try Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/uJ18WZ/1)

Explanation

`(\d+)(?:_)(?![\s\S]*\1)`

**1st Capturing Group** `(\d+)`

`\d+` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)

- Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

**Non-capturing group** `(?:_)`

`_` matches the character `_` literally (case sensitive)

**Negative Lookahead** `(?![\s\S]*\1)`

Assert that the Regex below does not match
Match a single character present in the list below `[\s\S]*`

- Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

`\S` matches any non-whitespace character (equal to `[^\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

`\1` matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group

Comment: The ids to capture are dynamic

Comment: @user7294900 but your question reads like that. do you know their range?

Comment: the above expression is ok but I don know the values which should come in the response and there are no only 2 values there are a lot of multiple repeted one I wan to make all unique

Comment: @biyyapu you can try it now, it is capturing multiple unique values.

Comment: @biyyapu I'm not the OP, biyyapu should say if it work

Comment: sorry I think u didn't understand my query. if there are 2 same responses I need to pic only one and there are lot of repeated responses .hope u understand my query

Comment: as I mentioned the responses which are repeated in that I need to capture one for each..

Comment: yes tried but not working it was capturing some other value from the response

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could capture the whole match in a group and capture the digits in a second group. Then use a negative lookahead to assert that what is captured in group 1 does not occur anymore giving you the unique values.

The digits you want to match are in capturing group 2. Note that to match the dot `.`  and the asterix `*` literally you have to escape them.

`(http://images\.(\d+)_120\*75)(?![\s\S]*\1)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hbjh4R/1)